# Copying data from rows to another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to manually select range in my master table and by clicking the button, copy the seleted data into another workbook. Below is the code I tried, however I got error everytime. I suppose the problem is that I do not need the line with opening the Master workbook because it will be opened everytime. Futhermore, I am not sure how to set the copy&paste ranges.

I would be grateful for any piece of advice!

[image]
[image]

```
 Sub foo()
Dim x As Workbook, y As Workbook

'## Open both workbooks first:
Set y = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Jakub\Desktop\Proforma.xlsm")
Set x = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Jakub\Desktop\MasterDATABASE.xlsm")

'Now, copy what you want from x:
Dim copyRng As Range
Set copyRng = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please select a range to be copied.", Title:="select range", Type:=8)

copyRng.Range("A1").Copy Destination:=y.Sheets("proforma").Range("B2")
copyRng.Range("C1").Copy Destination:=y.Sheets("proforma").Range("B3")
copyRng.Range("D1").Copy Destination:=y.Sheets("proforma").Range("B4")
copyRng.Range("B:B").Copy Destination:=y.Sheets("proforma").Range("A10")
copyRng.Range("E:E").Copy Destination:=y.Sheets("proforma").Range("C10")

End Sub
```

Comment: How can you rely on Selection when you have just opened the workbook?

Comment: I am not quite sure how can I answer you. Could you please clarify you question?

Comment: You say you want to select some cells and click a button but the code you have provided opens the MasterDATABASE workbook that contains the MasterTABLE worksheet and that contains the data and the button so **how** did you select the data and click the button to run the foo sub procedure on a closed workbook?

Comment: Yes, you are right, it does not make much sense. How should I adjust it? As for data selection, everytime I will select with a mouse the columns A-E, only sometimes it will be one row and sometimes it will be 10 rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use Application.InputBox():

```
Sub foo()
    Dim x As Workbook, y As Workbook

    '## Open both workbooks first:
    Set y = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Jakub\Desktop\Proforma.xlsm")
    Set x = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Jakub\Desktop\MasterDATABASE.xlsm")

'Now, copy what you want from x:
    Dim copyRng As Range
    Set copyRng = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please select a range to be copied.", Title:="select range", Type:=8)

    copyRng.Copy Destination:= y.Sheets("proforma").Range("A1")

   'Close x:
   x.Close
End Sub
```

You might want to add some code to check for user to select a valid range (please notice I opened x as the second workbook to have it “active” for the user to select a range of it)

Comment: @Jeame, did you try this?

Comment: Hello DisplayName. I was working fine. But when I put there ranges, one problem occured viz. my post below

Comment: Edited to remove a leftover Range(“A1”) after copyRng. Now the range selected by the user is being copied and pasted in sheet “proforma”  A1 cell

Answer (score 0):

Change,

```
copyRng.Range("B1:B999999").Copy Destination:=y.Sheets("proforma").Range("A10:A999999")
```

To,

```
copyRng.columns(2).Copy Destination:=y.Sheets("proforma").Range("A10")
copyRng.columns(5).Copy Destination:=y.Sheets("proforma").Range("C10")
```

You are dealing with a selection of cells so you can take the whole column of the selection.

You might not want to leave errors such as changes in the original selection's columns A, C & D to the user. This would require a loop that exits if A, C or D changes.

```
...
dim s as long, d as long
d = 10
with y.Sheets("proforma")
    .Range("B2") = copyRng.Range("A1").value
    .Range("B3") = copyRng.Range("C1").value
    .Range("B4") = copyRng.Range("D1").value
    for s = 1 to copyRng.Rows.count
        if copyRng.cells(s, "A") = .Range("B2") and _
           copyRng.cells(s, "C") = .Range("B3") and _
           copyRng.cells(s, "D") = .Range("B4") then
            .Range("A" & d) = copyRng.cells(s, "B").value
            .Range("C" & d) = copyRng.cells(s, "E").value
            d = d + 1
        else
            exit for
        end if
    next s
end with
```

Comment: In my first post I put my code at the moment, however I still get error 1004 (Application or object defind error). The problem would be in the lines below, because without them it works fine.
copyRng.Range("B:B").CopyDestination:=y.Sheets("proforma").Range("A10")
copyRng.Range("E:E").CopyDestination:=y.Sheets("proforma").Range("C10")

Comment: try it with columns instead of range as edit above. what range are you selecting? did you try the loop with error control?

Comment: Yes, with those columns it works fine! As for the loop, I would rather add to the end of the code sth like:   

ChDir "C:\Users\Jakub\Desktop"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\Jakub\Desktop\proforma.xlsm", _
        FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False

However, how can I adjust it so that when the file Proforma is generated, the first window the user would see would be the window asking, where to save copy of the file, what name it should have etc.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-getsaveasfilename-method-excel

Comment: Code below has to be in Proforma right? How can I then call this code from Masterdatabase?
                                                                                                              
Sub filesave()
    Dim bFileSaveAs As Boolean
    bFileSaveAs = Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs).Show
    If Not bFileSaveAs Then MsgBox "User cancelled", vbCritical
End Sub